# How do I include a COUNT field in SQL with multiple joins?

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, count, where

I have a SQL where I want to pull in all Landlords with more than one Pending Request. The trouble I'm having is not knowing where to place the syntax that will populate the field called 'NumberOfPendingRequests' and so that the syntax will validate.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is a shortened version of the SQL

```
SELECT
  Apartment.Representative__c
, Account.RecordTypeId
, Contact.Id
, COUNT(Request.Status__c) as 'NumberOfPendingRequests'

FROM Account_Salesforce Account
LEFT JOIN Apartment__c_Salesforce Apartment
ON Account.Id = Apartment.Owner__c

RIGHT JOIN Contact_Salesforce Contact
ON Contact.Id = Apartment.Representative__c

LEFT JOIN Request__c_Salesforce Request
ON Account.Id = Request.Landlord__c

WHERE
Account.RecordTypeId = '012580000004SxCAAU' AND
Request.Moveindate__c > GETDATE() AND
Request.Status__c = 'Pending'
Request.NumberOfPendingRequests > '1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe by using an `OUTER APPLY` you can prepare your data to be usable for the rest of your query. Something like the below (As a note, I did not test this, so it may need some modifications to fully work for your need):

```sql
SELECT
  Apartment.Representative__c
, Account.RecordTypeId
, Contact.Id
, cnt.NumberOfPendingRequests

FROM Account_Salesforce Account
LEFT JOIN Apartment__c_Salesforce Apartment
ON Account.Id = Apartment.Owner__c

RIGHT JOIN Contact_Salesforce Contact
ON Contact.Id = Apartment.Representative__c

OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 Req.Landlord__c, COUNT(Req.Status__c) as 'NumberOfPendingRequests'
  FROM [Request__c_Salesforce] Req
  WHERE Account.Id = Req.Landlord__c
  AND Req.Movindate__C > GetDate()
  AND Req.Status__c = 'Pending'
  GROUP BY Req.Landlord__c
) cnt

WHERE
Account.RecordTypeId = '012580000004SxCAAU' AND
Req.NumberOfPendingRequests > 1
```

Comment: Thanks Gortonington! I managed to get this SQL to run, however, it looks like 'NumberOfPendingRequests' field is counting ALL Request statuses after today's date, rather than all 'Pending' request statuses. Judging by your query though, this doesn't make sense. Do you have any further thoughts? I'll keep testing in the meantime. :)

Comment: In my test (simplified with dummy data) I do not run into same issue as you are. Perhaps I would investigate the relationships (WHERE statements and JOIN ON statements) to validate that logic. I usually find that to be where most issues are. @gregbeazley - good luck and hope you figure it out soon!

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing the `group by` and `having` parts of your query.

Not sure about your use of the `right join`.

Keep in mind that `GetDate()` returns a date *and* time, so it may be better to use `convert(date, getDate())` in your where-clause since it sets the time to midnight (or `00:00`).

```sql
SELECT
  apt.Representative__c
, act.RecordTypeId
, c.Id
, COUNT(r.Status__c) NumberOfPendingRequests
FROM Account_Salesforce act
LEFT JOIN Apartment__c_Salesforce apt ON apt.Owner__c = act.Id
LEFT JOIN Contact_Salesforce c ON c.Id = apt.Representative__c
LEFT JOIN Request__c_Salesforce r ON r.Landlord__c = act.Id
WHERE
act.RecordTypeId = '012580000004SxCAAU' 
AND r.Moveindate__c > GETDATE() 
AND r.Status__c = 'Pending'
group by   
  apt.Representative__c
, act.RecordTypeId
, c.Id
having COUNT(r.status__c) > 1
```

**Output**

| Representative__c | RecordTypeId | Id | NumberOfPendingRequests |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| contact1 | 012580000004SxCAAU | contact1 | 2 |

Try it yourself: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ftq614Q5)